# git doesn't stop tracking specific autogenerated file despite I excluded it in .gitignore and `.git/info/exclude`

Tags: git, gitignore

Git doesn't stop tracking specific autogenerated file in the project.
I have a specific file that autogenerated when the project run: `platform/views/index.html`. I have added it to `.gitignore`, to `.git/info/exclude`, run on it `git rm --cached platform/views/index.html` but every time it's recreated git keep asking me what do I want to do with it.

How can I cause git to stop tracking this file once and forever?
Thank you.

My `.gitignore` file:

```
dump.rdb
*.DS_Store
.vscode
.sfdx
npm-debug.log
**/.idea
**/node_modules
.vs
**/.history
newrelic_agent.log
platform/api/modules/interactions/entity-mock.js
platform/views/
```

Comment: Please, post your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Your goto command to debug gitignore issues : `git check-ignore -v <path/to/file>`

Comment: `A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of the  .gitignore file, with infinite depth.`

Comment: It seems correct. Did you try any of the solutions ar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore all files in the directory, use:

```
platform/views/**
```

in the gitignore. If you just want to ignore the one file, use:

```
platform/views/index.html
```

The pattern `platform/views` does not match the file, so your current .gitignore is not ignoring the file.

Comment: "your current .gitignore is not ignoring the file" are you sure ? from what I see the OP's pattern `platform/views/` should make git ignore all files within that directory (tested on my machine, git v2.31/linux)

Comment: @LeGEC, actually I would like to get some clarification regarding this pattern too, why it works for `node_modules` but doesn't work for other folder? I marked this answer as correct because it looks that after I've added `**` it started to ignore it finally.

Comment: AFAICT, `platform/views` should match, and as @LeGEC points out, my initial comment seems incorrect.  It's not clear to me why you're seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Files already committed will not be ignored.

1. Commit your .gitignore
2. Delete the file in question
3. Do another commit
4. Let the file be autogenerated again

And then verify that it isn't part of new commits after the steps above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest inspecting several things :

a. run `git check-ignore -v platform/views/index.html`

If the file is ignored : you will see a message, mentioning the gitignore file and the pattern within that gitignore file that ignores this specific path ;
if the file is not ignored : you will see an empty output.

b. if file is not ignored, run `git rm --cached platform/views/index.html` again, and confirm that after that, the file *is* ignored.

You may commit the result if relevant.

c. trigger your generation job manually, and see if that file is tracked again.

This would mean that your job runs the equivalent of `git add -f platform/views/index.html` somewhere.